# How to insert a blank line between different values of one column

Tags: shell, awk

I have 3 files `B1.dat`, `B2.dat` and `B3.dat` with numbers arranged in rows and columns, which I already convert into a file with three columns (one for B dat file) as follows:

```
(tr -s "[:space:]" "\n" < B1.dat) > B1c.dat
(tr -s "[:space:]" "\n" < B2.dat) > B2c.dat
(tr -s "[:space:]" "\n" < B3.dat) > B3c.dat
paste B1c.dat B2c.dat B3c.dat > dfsa3c.dat
```

the content of `dfsa3c.dat` is something like this

```
0.72    0.5 0.
0.72    1.5 0.
0.72    2.5 0.5045
0.72    3.5 1.
0.72    4.5 1.
0.72    5.5 1.
0.72    6.5 1.
0.72    7.5 1.
0.72    8.5 1.
0.72    9.5 1.
0.72    10.5    1.
0.72    11.5    1.
0.72    12.5    1.
0.76    0.5 0.
0.76    1.5 0.0005
0.76    2.5 0.6215
0.76    3.5 1.
0.76    4.5 1.
0.76    5.5 1.
0.76    6.5 1.
0.76    7.5 1.
0.76    8.5 1.
0.76    9.5 1.
0.76    10.5    1.
0.76    11.5    1.
0.76    12.5    1.
0.8 0.5 0.
0.8 1.5 0.00175
0.8 2.5 0.7495
0.8 3.5 1.
0.8 4.5 1.
0.8 5.5 1.
0.8 6.5 1.
0.8 7.5 1.
0.8 8.5 1.
0.8 9.5 1.
0.8 10.5    1.
0.8 11.5    1.
0.8 12.5    1.
0.84    0.5 0.
0.84    1.5 0.004
0.84    2.5 0.873
0.84    3.5 1.
0.84    4.5 1.
0.84    5.5 1.
0.84    6.5 1.
0.84    7.5 1.
0.84    8.5 1.
0.84    9.5 1.
0.84    10.5    1.
0.84    11.5    1.
0.84    12.5    1.
```

I would like to create this file data but inserting a blank line when the value of the first column changes, like this:

```
0.72    0.5 0.
0.72    1.5 0.
0.72    2.5 0.5045
0.72    3.5 1.
0.72    4.5 1.
0.72    5.5 1.
0.72    6.5 1.
0.72    7.5 1.
0.72    8.5 1.
0.72    9.5 1.
0.72    10.5    1.
0.72    11.5    1.
0.72    12.5    1.

0.76    0.5 0.
0.76    1.5 0.0005
0.76    2.5 0.6215
0.76    3.5 1.
0.76    4.5 1.
0.76    5.5 1.
0.76    6.5 1.
0.76    7.5 1.
0.76    8.5 1.
0.76    9.5 1.
0.76    10.5    1.
0.76    11.5    1.
0.76    12.5    1.

0.8 0.5 0.
0.8 1.5 0.00175
0.8 2.5 0.7495
0.8 3.5 1.
0.8 4.5 1.
0.8 5.5 1.
0.8 6.5 1.
0.8 7.5 1.
0.8 8.5 1.
0.8 9.5 1.
0.8 10.5    1.
0.8 11.5    1.
0.8 12.5    1.

0.84    0.5 0.
0.84    1.5 0.004
0.84    2.5 0.873
0.84    3.5 1.
0.84    4.5 1.
0.84    5.5 1.
0.84    6.5 1.
0.84    7.5 1.
0.84    8.5 1.
0.84    9.5 1.
0.84    10.5    1.
0.84    11.5    1.
0.84    12.5    1.
```

The original data file has much more values, and thus the script should detect when to insert the blank line.

Comment: You **could** do everything with just 1 `awk` script instead of 3 `tr`s then a `paste` then an `awk` and 4 temp files. Ask a new question if you'd like help with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'p!=$1{p=$1;if(NR>1) print ""}1' file
```